# switch case doesn't work, ignores methods instead

Tags: java, arrays, switch-statement

I am trying to use a switch statement instead of a series of if/elses, but when I run the code only the first two cases run properly while the others are ignored. I've tested the methods with the if conditions and it worked fine, but I want to use the switch statements. (some methods I haven't gotten to yet hence the comments)

input: A 25
output: 25 is added to the Bag.
input: F 25
output: There is (1) 25 in the Bag.
input: S
output: (nothing)
expected output: There are 1 numbers in the Bag.
input: m
output: (nothing)
expected output: The minimum number in the Bag is 25.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bag {

int index = 0;
int[] array = new int[50];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0;
    Bag bag = new Bag();

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (x == 0) {
    System.out.print("Add(A), Delete(D), Find(F), Size(S), Min(m), Max(M), List(L), Quit(Q) >> ");
    char c = scan.next().charAt(0);
    int y = scan.nextInt();
    switch(c) {
    case 'A': bag.Add(y);
    break;
    //case 'D': bag.Delete(y);
    //break;
    case 'F': bag.Find(y);
    break;
    case 'S': bag.Size();
    break;
    case 'm': bag.Min();
    break;
    case 'M': bag.Max();
    break;
    /*case 'L': bag.List();
    break;
    case 'Q': bag.Quit();*/
    }

}
}
public void Add(int y) {
    array[index] = y;
    index++;
    System.out.println("   " + y + " is added to the Bag. ");
}
  public void Find(int y)
   {
     int count = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       if (array[i] == y) {
          count++;
        }
      }
      System.out.println("   There is (" + count + ") " + y
                + " in the Bag.");

          }
public void Size() {
    System.out.println("  There are " + index + " numbers in the Bag.");
}

public void Min() {
    int min = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < index; i++) {
        if(min > array[i]) {
            min = array[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("   The minimum number in the Bag is " + min + ".");
}
public void Max() {
    int max = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < index; i++) {
        if(max < array[i]) {
            max = array[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("   The minimum number in the Bag is " + max + ".");
}

}
```

Comment: What are your inputs? Why doesn't it "work"?

Comment: What isn't working are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Please post input , output and expected output

Comment: when i input any of the letters (in this case m, M or S) i don't get anything back, but when i input A or F and a number, it works fine. the code compiles fine, and in the console when i input one of the 3 mentioned letters it doesn't give anything back.

Comment: The `Max()` have a wrong sysout, `"   The minimum number in the Bag is " + max + ".");` maybe you think that is calling minimum.

Comment: It expects you to type a number for any case, not just for `A` and `F`... So I expect it to wait at the line `int y = scan.nextInt();` if you just type `m`.

Comment: The case statement is fine...There is something else going on.

Comment: @imaginedrragon it is always waiting for you to enter the `nextInt()` so in your latter cases it is never making it to the `switch` statement. Just like @blm said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your code.

```
char c = scan.next().charAt(0); //Here you first expect char (program waiting for a input)
int y = scan.nextInt(); //And here you expect int (program waiting for a input)
```

I thing something like this should work.

```
System.out.print("Add(A), Delete(D), Find(F), Size(S), Min(m), Max(M), List(L), Quit(Q) >> ");
char c = scan.next().charAt(0);
switch (c) {
    case 'A':
        int y = scan.nextInt(); // here you need next input
        bag.Add(y);
        break;
    case 'F':
        int y = scan.nextInt(); // here you need next input
        bag.Find(y);
        break;
    case 'S':
        bag.Size();
        break;
    case 'm':
        bag.Min();
        break;
    case 'M':
        bag.Max();
        break;
}
```

Comment: Same variable name in both cases will cause to compile time error. If the int y in case 'F' is changed to some other variable name, this code will be a possible solution.

Comment: that's exactly what happened, and changing the second variable to z seemed to have worked. thank you everyone, i understand this better now!

Answer (score 2):

You're always reading an int, even in the cases that don't need them, like "m", "M", or "S. If you type M`<return>`0`<return>`, it will print the max, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in your call to `scan.nextInt()` everytime, even if your selected option does not require a second argument.

`Scanner` methods such as `next()`, `nextInt()`, etc, will always hang the console waiting for your input. Since it always requires two inputs, you were missing a second argument. That's why it didn't print anything.

```
while (x == 0) {
    System.out.print("Add(A), Delete(D), Find(F), Size(S), Min(m), Max(M), List(L), Quit(Q) >> ");
    char c = scan.next().charAt(0);
    int y = 0;
    switch (c) {
        case 'A':
            y = scan.nextInt();
            bag.Add(y);
            break;
        //case 'D': bag.Delete(y);
        //break;
        case 'F':
            y = scan.nextInt();
            bag.Find(y);
            break;
        case 'S':
            bag.Size();
            break;
        case 'm':
            bag.Min();
            break;
        case 'M':
            bag.Max();
            break;
    }
}
```